# Highlighting boxes that have very specific conditions in geom_bar()

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I would like to highlight just a few of the boxes that follow a certain condition in my geom_bar() plot by making their outlines thicker.

Labels for my conditions are:

```
colors = c('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l')
health = c('very_good', 'good', 'moderate', 'bad', 'very_bad')
smoking_status = c('Current_Smoker','Ex-Smoker','Nonsmoke')
```

Code for my plot is:

```
smoking_health %>%
 ggplot(aes(health, colors_percentage, fill = colors))+
   geom_bar(stat = 'identity', color = 'black')+
   facet_grid(~ smoking_status, scale = 'free', space = 'free_x')+
 scale_fill_manual(values = palette)+
 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1, size = 8))
```

I want to highlight the conditions:

```
(smoking_status == 'Nonsmoke' & health == 'Moderate' & (colors %in% c('c', 'f'))) |
  (smoking_status == 'Current_Smoker' & health == 'very_bad' & colors == 'e')
```

This is what I want for my final plot:

[image]

I can't seem to find a way to bolden the outline of these kind of specific conditions.

Does anyone know a way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Next time, use `dput` to make `smoking_health` into code that results in the sample. What you wrote still needs to be wrapped around a `smoking_health <- tibble(<what you wrote>)`, before we get `smoking_health`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have your data to reproduce your plot, but this approach should work for you. It relies on the fact that `geom_bar` can be given a `size` aesthetic to determine the width of its outline. You can create a new column in your data frame based on the logical rules you wish to use to highlight specific boxes, and feed this to the `size` parameter inside `aes`. Remember to add a `scale_size_manual` call to choose the width of the lines you want to use for normal and highlighted boxes.

```r
smoking_health %>%
  mutate(highlighted = (smoking_status == 'Nonsmoker' & 
                        health == 'moderate' & colors %in% c("l", "a")) |
                       (smoking_status == 'Current_Smoker' & health == "very_good" &
                       colors == "j")) %>%
   ggplot(aes(health, colors_percentage, fill = colors))+
   geom_bar(aes(size = highlighted),
            stat = 'identity', color = 'black', position = "fill") +
   facet_grid(~ smoking_status, scale = 'free', space = 'free_x') +
   scale_fill_manual(values = palette) +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(0.5, 2)) +
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1, size = 8)) +
   theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Note that you can easily add a color scale using the same trick to make the boxes stand out even more:

```r
smoking_health %>%
  mutate(highlighted = (smoking_status == 'Nonsmoker' & 
                        health == 'moderate' & colors %in% c("l", "a")) |
                       (smoking_status == 'Current_Smoker' & health == "very_good" &
                       colors == "j")) %>%
   ggplot(aes(health, colors_percentage, fill = colors))+
   geom_bar(aes(size = highlighted, color = highlighted),
            stat = 'identity', position = "fill") +
   facet_grid(~ smoking_status, scale = 'free', space = 'free_x') +
   scale_fill_manual(values = palette) +
   scale_size_manual(values = c(0.5, 2)) +
   scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "red")) +
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1, size = 8)) +
   theme(legend.position = "none")
```

### [image]

**Data used**

```r
smoking_health <- structure(list(colors_percentage = c(
  0.424281163606793,  0.757145850220695, 
0.272088683908805, 0.702225066488609, 0.783901083283126, 0.31812732364051, 
0.25504200020805, 0.150501632830128, 0.949092260561883, 0.176580579485744, 
0.597438448341563, 0.490371913416311, 0.310657090973109, 0.690649163676426, 
0.815282948082313, 0.119425331009552, 0.112637027399614, 0.48738272418268, 
0.628815256524831, 0.691388996317983, 0.516097098588943, 0.349926907802001, 
0.894879485014826, 0.884916280163452, 0.683286903426051, 0.560128865065053, 
0.87698360090144, 0.875387869309634, 0.62485910882242, 0.182680936297402, 
0.827586045023054, 0.641206950880587, 0.920631993561983, 0.156408043345436, 
0.696290905354545, 0.862210909835994, 0.59949598624371, 0.627007181989029, 
0.671079852851108, 0.68094572937116, 0.52527018962428, 0.232511073350906, 
0.671282195718959, 0.572535041952506, 0.00735216797329485, 0.217277518706396, 
0.715195999480784, 0.998276757542044, 0.357245847582817, 0.645074530970305, 
0.643338346853852, 0.0380584141239524, 0.0638308054767549, 0.674578275764361, 
0.176417721668258, 0.0331670793239027, 0.21982069965452, 0.650513555621728, 
0.303580678766593, 0.11516772210598, 0.0128057508263737, 0.114486665232107, 
0.598777604289353, 0.759205947630107, 0.581150981364772, 0.649594946065918, 
0.290496403817087, 0.772731678327546, 0.57460440415889, 0.474307884462178, 
0.421877446817234, 0.638829972362146, 0.0785523615777493, 0.345375114353374, 
0.187747624702752, 0.545154723571613, 0.309543700655922, 0.891319246962667, 
0.72464850358665, 0.528383505064994, 0.0506025629583746, 0.286434431327507, 
0.81406940240413, 0.920075967442244, 0.136473591905087, 0.990138751687482, 
0.950963140232489, 0.32558137900196, 0.614674870390445, 0.881066406844184, 
0.181831295602024, 0.8991091218777, 0.937552833463997, 0.277483612066135, 
0.986416225554422, 0.626976334722713), colors = c("a", "b", "c", 
"f", "i", "k", "l", "c", "d", "e", "f", "i", "l", "b", "c", "f", 
"g", "h", "i", "l", "c", "e", "f", "i", "j", "k", "l", "c", "f", 
"h", "i", "l", "a", "b", "c", "f", "i", "k", "l", "c", "d", "e", 
"f", "i", "l", "b", "c", "f", "g", "h", "i", "l", "c", "e", "f", 
"i", "j", "k", "l", "c", "f", "h", "i", "l", "a", "b", "c", "f", 
"i", "k", "l", "c", "d", "e", "f", "i", "l", "b", "c", "f", "g", 
"h", "i", "l", "c", "e", "f", "i", "j", "k", "l", "c", "f", "h", 
"i", "l"), smoking_status = c("Current_Smoker", "Ex-Smoker", 
"Nonsmoker", "Nonsmoker", "Nonsmoker", "Ex-Smoker", "Nonsmoker", 
"Nonsmoker", "Current_Smoker", "Ex-Smoker", "Nonsmoker", "Nonsmoker", 
"Nonsmoker", "Ex-Smoker", "Nonsmoker", "Nonsmoker", "Current_Smoker", 
"Ex-Smoker", "Nonsmoker", "Nonsmoker", "Nonsmoker", "Ex-Smoker", 
"Nonsmoker", "Nonsmoker", "Current_Smoker", "Ex-Smoker", "Nonsmoker", 
"Nonsmoker", "Nonsmoker", "Ex-Smoker", "Nonsmoker", "Nonsmoker", 
"Current_Smoker", "Ex-Smoker", "Nonsmoker", "Nonsmoker", "Nonsmoker", 
"Ex-Smoker", "Nonsmoker", "Nonsmoker", "Current_Smoker", "Ex-Smoker", 
"Nonsmoker", "Nonsmoker", "Nonsmoker", "Ex-Smoker", "Nonsmoker", 
"Nonsmoker", "Current_Smoker", "Ex-Smoker", "Nonsmoker", "Nonsmoker", 
"Nonsmoker", "Ex-Smoker", "Nonsmoker", "Nonsmoker", "Current_Smoker", 
"Ex-Smoker", "Nonsmoker", "Nonsmoker", "Nonsmoker", "Ex-Smoker", 
"Nonsmoker", "Nonsmoker", "Current_Smoker", "Ex-Smoker", "Nonsmoker", 
"Nonsmoker", "Nonsmoker", "Ex-Smoker", "Nonsmoker", "Nonsmoker", 
"Current_Smoker", "Ex-Smoker", "Nonsmoker", "Nonsmoker", "Nonsmoker", 
"Ex-Smoker", "Nonsmoker", "Nonsmoker", "Current_Smoker", "Ex-Smoker", 
"Nonsmoker", "Nonsmoker", "Nonsmoker", "Ex-Smoker", "Nonsmoker", 
"Nonsmoker", "Current_Smoker", "Ex-Smoker", "Nonsmoker", "Nonsmoker", 
"Nonsmoker", "Ex-Smoker", "Nonsmoker", "Nonsmoker"), health = c("very_good", 
"good", "moderate", "very_good", "bad", "very_good", "good", 
"very_bad", "very_good", "good", "moderate", "very_good", "bad", 
"very_good", "good", "very_bad", "very_good", "good", "moderate", 
"very_good", "bad", "very_good", "good", "very_bad", "very_good", 
"good", "moderate", "very_good", "bad", "very_good", "good", 
"very_bad", "very_good", "good", "moderate", "very_good", "bad", 
"very_good", "good", "very_bad", "very_good", "good", "moderate", 
"very_good", "bad", "very_good", "good", "very_bad", "very_good", 
"good", "moderate", "very_good", "bad", "very_good", "good", 
"very_bad", "very_good", "good", "moderate", "very_good", "bad", 
"very_good", "good", "very_bad", "very_good", "good", "moderate", 
"very_good", "bad", "very_good", "good", "very_bad", "very_good", 
"good", "moderate", "very_good", "bad", "very_good", "good", 
"very_bad", "very_good", "good", "moderate", "very_good", "bad", 
"very_good", "good", "very_bad", "very_good", "good", "moderate", 
"very_good", "bad", "very_good", "good", "very_bad")), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 6L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 21L, 24L, 26L, 
27L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 36L, 39L, 41L, 42L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 
51L, 54L, 56L, 57L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 66L, 69L, 71L, 72L, 75L, 
76L, 77L, 78L, 81L, 84L, 86L, 87L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 96L, 99L, 
101L, 102L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 111L, 114L, 116L, 117L, 120L, 
121L, 122L, 123L, 126L, 129L, 131L, 132L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 
141L, 144L, 146L, 147L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 156L, 159L, 161L, 
162L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 171L, 174L, 176L, 177L, 180L), class = "data.frame")

palette <- c("#40004B", "#622E6B", "#855C8C", "#A88BAD", "#CAB9CD", "#EDE7EE", 
"#E7EEEA", "#B9CCC0", "#8BAA97", "#5C876D", "#2E6544", "#00441B")
```